# TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given) when I'm actually giving one (Python-Flask & CouchDBKit)

Tags: python

I'm trying to make Flask work with CouchDB but still can't for obscure reasons.

I just started a minimal application so to nail down problems more easily, still to no avail.

Here's my app code:

```
import datetime
from couchdbkit import *
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

class Post(Document):
    title = StringProperty()
    content = StringProperty()

server = Server()
db = server.get_or_create_db('test')      
Post.set_db(db)

post = **Post.view('post/all')**

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return post

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here's the debug output from Flask:

```
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

And here the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in full_dispatch_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1577, in make_response
    rv = self.response_class.force_type(rv, request.environ)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 824, in force_type
    response = BaseResponse(*_run_wsgi_app(response, environ))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 854, in run_wsgi_app
    app_iter = app(environ, start_response)
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

if I run **Post.view('post/all')** outside of the route definition it works..

I've also tried to follow the official tutorial line by line, but I'm assuming it's outdated or the author assumes I've modules he didn't mention..?

Answer (score 2):

Your view doesn't return a string, tuple or WSGI response.

Flask sees it is not a string or tuple, so it tries to treat it as a WSGI response, which means it'll get called with `environ` and `start_response` arguments.

Return an actual valid response from your `index` view instead of the `post` object. See the [About Responses section](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart/#about-responses) of the Flask Quickstart.

You might want to use the [Flask-CouchDB integration package](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-CouchDB/).